# Service bus queue message Content convert to string with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azureservicebus

I use rest api with powershell to get details from the Service Bus queue message. I am not sure when it happened, but now Content is in bytes ex: Content:{64, 6, 115, 116…}.
How can I convert it to the normal string with data?

```
function Get-SAStoken {
    param (
      $QueueName,
      $Access_Policy_Name,
      $Access_Policy_Key
    )
    $expireInSeconds = 300
  
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web")| out-null
      $uri="my.servicebus.windows.net/$QueueName"
      #Token expires now+300
      $expires=([DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds())+ $expireInSeconds
      $signatureString=[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($uri)+ "`n" + [string]$expires
      $HMAC = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
      $HMAC.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($Access_Policy_Key)
      $signature = $HMAC.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($signatureString))
      $signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
     
      $sasToken = "SharedAccessSignature sr={0}&sig={1}&se={2}&skn={3}" -f  [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($uri), 
                                                                            [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($signature), 
                                                                            [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($expires), 
                                                                            [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($Access_Policy_Name)
          
    return $sasToken 
}

function Get-SBmessage {
    param (
      $SASToken,
      $Queue
    )  
    $queue = $Queue
    $header = @{ Authorization = $SASToken } 
    $postService = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://my.servicebus.windows.net/$queue/messages/head" `
                                   -Headers $header `
                                   -Method Post 
                                
      
      return $postService
      
}

$Queue = "capacity-checker"
$SAStokenRunningTest = Get-SAStoken -QueueName $Queue  -Access_Policy_Name "pipeline" -Access_Policy_Key "key-for-sb-queue"

$SBmessage = Get-SBmessage -SASToken $SAStokenRunningTest -Queue $Queue
$SBmessage
```

Comment: `$SBmessage.Content.GetType().Name` is `byte[]`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen String

Comment: But in the question it says "now Content is in bytes ex: Content:{64, 6, 115, 116…}" - can you show exactly what's displayed?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen in $SBmessage.Content there is a lot of different numbers, like this 
73
49
78
105
73
115
73
110
103
49
100
67
73
54
73
109
57
80
100
109
78
54
78
85
49
102
78
51
65

I missed that API response return it like String, but not like byte array. It was my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my solution is

```
[byte[]]$bytes = $SBmessage.Content
$msContent = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes)
```

Thanks, @MathiasR.Jessen for the help